# Pre-Populate a Windows Command Prompt Windows with Text

Tags: windows, command-prompt

does anyone know if there is a way (programatically or not) to open up a windows command prompt window and pre-populate it with text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `CMD.EXE /K ECHO The Text`

Answer (score 0):

Create a batchfile (.bat) that uses the type command, then open that:

```
echo "Hello World"
echo "Insert junk here"
cmd.exe
```

Comment: @Matteo That's correct. Been a while since i've written any CMD.